# How to compile a project in the terminal that was cloned from a github repository into Xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, compiler-errors, g++

I would like to compile a c++ project in the terminal that I have in xCode. That is, in xCode my project compiles by clicking the 'run' button but I would like to compile the same project in the terminal through command line prompts. As I understand, xCode is only operational within a MacOs machine and I would like to a) compile my project on my MacOS using the terminal and then b) compile my project in a linux based environment using the command line.

My Xcode project was cloned from code on a github repository so I have a directory containing the project code on my machine. Is it possible to compile the xCode project using the code that is in the `src`folder of that directory?

So far I have tried

`g++ main.cpp -std=c++11`

in the `src`folder but there is problems with

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` and then at the end

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

so possibly I have to append the command line compilation attempt with something?

Comment: If all you want to do is build your Xcode project from the command line on your macOS system, what's wrong with [`xcodebuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Hi, thanks, if possible I do not want to use this because as mentioned in my OP I would like to also compile in a linux environment (I am moving my code to an external server later) so I thought it would be good to first compile using command line on a macOS first and then use the same or similar command line in linux.

Comment: If you're targeting a multiple platform then I strongly advise managing a cmake build instead. It would allow you to target macOS (it literally generates the Xcode project for you, or ninja, or makefiles), Linux (generates makefiles, ninja, etc), and lord-knows how many other build environments (within the confines of your source, of course). If its a small project it would probably only take you a few minutes to craft the cmakelist.txt to get what you want. Anyway, that's how I would probably do it.

Comment: A makefile could help here. Can’t really help if you don’t provide the exact files you are trying to build.